# How to pass the dynamic state and setState to function typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I want to pass the dynamic state and setState into a function with Typescript. But, typescript is complaining about it. I tried using Generic, but it's not working.

```
  const handleSelectTag = (tag: { color: string; label: string }) => {
    if (!selectedShape) return;
    const updateShape = <Type>(state: Type, setState: (arg: Type) => void) => {
      if (Array.isArray(state)) {
        setState([...state, { color: tag.color }]);
      }
    };
    const { type } = selectedShape;
    if (type === 'rectangles') {
      updateShape(rectangles, setRectangles);
    } else if (type === 'ellipses') {
      updateShape(ellipses, setEllipses);
    }
  };
```

.When I update the state by calling setState inside a function, it's giving me this error

```
Argument of type '(Type & any[])[number][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type'.
  'Type' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '(Type & any[])[number][]'

How do I resolve this?
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you are calling setState inside the updateShape function you are spreading a generic type with an object literal type. e.g

```
setState([...state, { color: tag.color }])
```

On this line the type you are creating is `Array<Type[number] & { color: string }>`, which does not match the expected arg of `T` in the setState function.

As your state is an array, it would be easier to make the generic type the type of item in the array (in your case a shape). By doing this you can then change the parameters to be `Array<Type>`, which will allow you to spread the original state inside of the setState function. e.g

```
const updateShape = <Type>(state: Array<Type>, setState: (arg: Array<Type>) => void) => {
    ...
    setState([...state, { color: tag.color }];
    ...
}
```

However, you still have a problem trying to create the `Array<Type>` because you are spreading the generic `Type` and object literal of `{ color: string }`, which does not create the `Array<Type>` that you need. For example:

```
const newState = [...state, { color: tag.color }]; // Creates this type: Array<Type & { color: string }>
```

To solve this, you will need to cast the object literal to `Type`. As you are casting to a generic type, TS has no way of knowing that the object literal has sufficient overlap to cast correctly. Therefore, you must cast it to unknown first:

```
const newState: Array<Type> = [...state, { color: tag.color } as unknown as Type];
```

So your final `updateShape` function would look more like this:

```
 const updateShape = <Type>(state: Array<Type>, setState: (arg: Array<Type>) => void) => {
      if (Array.isArray(state)) {
        setState([...state, { color: tag.color } as unknown as Type]);
      }
    };
```